# Facebook login error using Flutter after install (Android)

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter, dart

I have a problem using the Facebook login in Flutter after installing into an Android device

My app was running fine with my Android device connected by USB (not using a virtual device), but when I build apk and install it using:

```
flutter build apk
flutter install
```

I cannot able to login using facebook, It always gives `FacebookLoginStatus.error`

I m using: `flutter_facebook_login: ^1.2.0`

I created 2 different facebook apps and the results were the same.

Whats missing? Thanks in advance!

Below is the source code what I have achieved so far:

```
void initiateFacebookLogin() async {

  var facebookLoginResult =
    await globals.facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email','public_profile']);

  print("face result ${facebookLoginResult.status}");

   switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
    case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
      showWarning('ERRO no login! Por favor, tente novamente!', context);
      break;
    case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
      showWarning('Login cancelado pelo usuário!', context);
      break;
    case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
      //print("LoggedIn");
      var graphResponse = await http.get(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=${facebookLoginResult
            .accessToken.token}');

      profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);

      print(profile.toString());

      Cadastro.name=profile['name'];
      Cadastro.firstName=profile['firstname'];
      Cadastro.lastName=profile['lastname'];
      Cadastro.email=profile['email'];
      Cadastro.id=profile['id'];

      findUser(profile['email'],profile['email'],true).then((bool value){

        //print("find user $value");
        //if(value==false)
        //  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Cadastro.tag);
      });

      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did understand what it´s missing. I was create only a hash for debug mode:keytool -exportcert -alias [my_production_alias] -keystore [my_certificate] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: Have you build apk in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

If the Facebook login works fine in debug mode, it's likely that you've only configured the debug key hash for the app. For the app to work properly on release/signed APK, the SHA key for the release build should be added as well. You can check the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#6--provide-the-development-and-release-key-hashes-for-your-app) for more details on setting up Facebook login.